# Validations: When mapping ranges of dates, how to only map a range when card does not match another card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm setting up a validation, where a person can only add a price if that period does not have a price yet. So for everything works as expected and my form return a validation error when it is supposed to.

A problem arrises when I would like to check if there is a `card` (e.g. discount card). ==> as a period is allowed to overlap if the `card` does not match.

validator

```
class AccommodationPriceAvailabilityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    accommodation_prices = AccommodationPrice.where("accommodation_category_id =?", record.accommodation_category_id)
    accommodation_price = AccommodationPrice.where("id=?", record.id)

    if accommodation_price.empty?

      #below code works, without checking the card =>
      date_ranges = accommodation_prices.map { |b| (b.start_date..b.end_date)}

      #attempt below to include the card, but not working =>
      date_ranges = accommodation_prices.where.not(:card => record.card).map { |b| (b.start_date..b.end_date)}

      #rest of the code
      date_ranges.each do |range|
        if range.include? value
          record.errors.add(attribute, "is overlapping with another period")
        end
      end
    else
      date_ranges = accommodation_prices.where.not('id=?', record.id).map { |b| b.start_date..b.end_date }
      date_ranges.each do |range|
        if range.include? value
          record.errors.add(attribute, "is overlapping with another period")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "not working" you mean your query is not retrieving all therecords you want, it is because you are adding a condition to an Activerecord which is already filtered by another where statement.

```
class AccommodationPrice < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :accommodation_category

  scope :without_card, -> (card) { where().not(card: card) }
  scope :all_except, -> (id) { where().not(id: id) }

  def self.by_category(id)
    where(accommodation_category_id: id)
  end

  def range
    start_date..end_date
  end
end

class AccommodationCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :accommodation_price
end

class AccommodationPriceAvailabilityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    accommodation_prices = AccommodationPrice.by_category(record.accommodation_category_id)
    accommodation_price = AccommodationPrice.find(record.id)

    if accommodation_price
      accomodations_filtered = accommodation_prices.all_except(record.id)
    else
      accomodations_filtered = AccommodationPrice.without_card(record.card)
    end

    to_accomodation_date_ranges(accomodations_filtered).each do |range|
      if range.include? value
        record.errors.add(attribute, "is overlapping with another period")
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def to_accomodation_date_ranges(accomodation_prices)
    accomodation_prices.map { |b| b.range }
  end
end
```